# Why Exception class isn't abstract?

Tags: java, exception

Once all Exceptions that can occur in our program are from specific concrete sub-classes of Exception class or Error class, then why Exception class isn't defined as abstract?

Comment: because you can throw new exception :)

Comment: Your statement is not quite correct. All throwable exceptions are subclasses of [`Throwable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html). This class is not abstract either and the question is: why should it be? There are no abstract methods in this class.

Comment: @Turing85 There is a definite case in favor of OP's suggestion, given the way exceptions were intended to be used. All of `Throwable`, `Excepton`, and `Error` may have been abstract classes. Abstract methods are not relevant here, but instantiation.

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia You've got it inside-out: because `Exception` is not abstract, you can instantiate it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think this is kind of a design philosophy thing. What good is an abstract class if it does not have any abstract methods? You simply deny the user instantiation of these objects without any (good) reason, which is inconvenient (it is different if you specifically deny instantiation when using e.g. a builder pattern).

Comment: Already asked here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/119668/abstract-exception-super-type

Comment: @Turing85 How do you know there is no good reason? Preventing the programmer from ever throwing a generic checked exception definitely qualifies as a good reason.

Comment: @user35443 The question you link to is about C#, with the key distinction that there are no checked exceptions there. I agree that throwing a generic `RuntimeException` makes sense many times.

Comment: @Turing85 Again, you're looking at it the wrong way around. Is there any reason why you should be able to instantiate a raw `Exception`? I can't see any, can you? So make it abstract then. It's a perfectly valid argument. On a very basic level OOP is about building a model of the world and if something doesn't make sense in the modelled world, it shouldn't be allowed in your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all Exceptions that can occur in our program are from specific
>   concrete sub-classes of Exception class

This is not correct. If in your code you don't need to create a new specific Exception class but you need to through a generic exception you can always do the following:

```
throw new Exception("Generic Exception");
```

The same can be said about the class `Object`. Why isn't `Object` declared as abstract? Because you can use it directly if needed. For example as a lock for synchronized blocks of code.

Comment: i know that we have this permission to do this, but who finally does it? its very vague in my opinion

Comment: @TheodoraBaxevani The thing is that this design choice is very, very old. In retrospect, exceptions should probably be designed in another way, but at the time, they probably thought it was a good idea to be able to throw `new Exception()`. Since it's possible, lots of programs do it. And since Java cares very much about backwards compatibility, they can't change that design anymore: it would break existing code.

Comment: There is no reason to make it abstract. The purpose of abstract is to define a skeleton for the subclasses that needs to rewrite abstract methods. Also if an abstract class with only concrete methods is possible why make it abstract?

Comment: I must agree with OP that a _checked_ generic exception is one of the greatest stupidities Java allows you.

Comment: Davide, abstract classes are those which are not allowed to be instantiated. Having an abstract method is a sufficient, but by no means a necessary condition to prevent instantiation.

Comment: A class should be made abstract because it's conceptually the right thing to do, not because there are some abstract methods in it. And conceptually there are some very good arguments for making `Exception` abstract and none really for making it an instantiable class.

Comment: @Marko why an Exception must be subclassed? There is no reason other than adding some useful information to it. The most generic Exception is Exception, otherwyse the right choice should be define Exception as abstract, and add a new concrete class GenericException that is possible to use for all the situations where there is nothing special to add to the Exception that must be thrown. Making Exception not abstract is simpler than adding a new class.

Comment: You don't seem to fully comprehend the nature of checked exceptions. Their intention is to warn the caller that a _specific_ kind of trouble can result from the call. Everybody already knows that _some_ kind of trouble can always arise. Only exceptions which have a chance to be meaningfully handled should be checked. What is the difference between an `OutOfMemoryError` and a generic `Exception`, in terms of the ability to meaningfully handle it?

Comment: @Marko OutOfMemoryError is not an Exception (and also not a generic Error, but a specific error). There are also Exceptions that are not needed to be intercepted (RuntimeException). Who said that the intention is to warn for a specific kind of trouble? If the idea was to block the possibility to through generic Exceptions as you said Exception has been bad designed, because as you said it should be abstract. The idea of the creator of Exception probably was to permit to through an Exception.

Comment: You mostly misunderstood my comment. `Exception` is a checked exception. If you throw it, you must declare `throws Exception`. That makes no sense with respect to the intention behind the language feature of checked exceptions. No method should ever `throws Exception` except callback methods which are forced into it by other bad aspects of the design of checked exceptions.

Comment: `The idea of the creator of Exception probably was to permit to throw an Exception.` Yes, but that idea was wrong. It was a bad design choice as it semantically doesn't make sense. As Marko explained, only exceptions you can do something about should be checked exceptions, everything else should be a `RuntimeException` or an `Error`. And there's nothing you can do about something as broad as a plain `Exception`.